# Standardize Addresses through R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file with columns Emailadress, Address1,Address2, city, state where data is not unique

```
EmailAddress    Address1                    Address2   City       State
xyz@gmail.com   510 E. Fellows St., unit 2             Fallon      NV
abc@yahoo.com   4432 Lockhill Selma Rd.                Sarosta     FL
```

I want these address to be standardized and periods spaces between and in the end to be removed. For that I tried gsub but no success. I also want St spell as street, Rd as Road.

Desired Output:

```
EmailAddress    Address1                  Address2   City       State
   xyz@gmail.com   510 East Fellows Street,Unit 2       Fallon      NV
   abc@yahoo.com   4432 Lockhill Selma Road             Sarosta     FL
```

I have tried

```
Address <- read.csv("c:Desktop\\New Folder\\Address.csv", header=T, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
A_df <- as.data.frame(Address)
Address1 <- gsub("\\.", "", A_df$Address1)
```

This is not giving me desired output. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me. Unless you want it in the dataframe instead of a vector. I'd probably remove any periods at the end. It just works with `regex` patterns, so that should give you the pattern to use.

```
A_df$Address1 <- gsub("\\Rd", "Road", A_df$Address1)
A_df$Address1 <- gsub("\\St.", "Street", A_df$Address1)
A_df$Address1 <- gsub("\\.", "", A_df$Address1)
```

Comment: This part is working for me too but i want Rd to be as Road, st as street too. Any help with that?? and also how to have all columns in final report